# equivalence relations questions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Question $1$: Let $S = \{1,2,3,4,...,9\}$. Let $R$ be the relation on the power set of $S$ defined by:
for every $X,Y$ in the power set of $S$, $XRY$ iff $\{1,2,3\}$ is a subset of $X$ or $Y$.

Is the following true?

$1$: for every $X$ in the power set, there exists a set $Y$ in the power set such that $XRY$. I think this one is true because we can choose $Y$ to be $\{1,2,3\}$.

$2$: There exists a set $X$ in the power set such that for every $Y$ in the power set, $XRY$. I think this one is also true because $X$ can be $\{1,2,3\}$ and the relation will hold.

$3$: how many sets $X$ in the power set are there such that $XR\{1\}$ are there?
I think the answer is $2^7$ because $X$ has to have $\{1,2\}$ in this case but for the rest of the elements we can either put them or not, it doesn't matter.

Question 2: let $A = \{1,2,3,....,250\}$. Define $R$ on $A$ cross $A$ by
for any $(a,b)$ , $(c,d)$ in $A$ cross $A$, $(a,b)R(c,d)$ iff $a+b = c+d$.

1: How many equivalence classes does R have? Explain
I'm not sure about this one but I think it is (250 choose 2) ? if that is true how can I explain it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Agree with 1 and 2. 3 is on the right track. If by "is a subset of $X$ or $Y$" you mean "is a subset of $X\cup Y$" then the answer is right, though you meant $X$ has to have $2$ and $3$ (not $1$ and $2$). If it means "is a subset of $X$ or a subset of $Y$", then it's wrong. You need to have $\{1,2,3\}\subseteq X$ since its not a subset of $\{1\},$ so there are $2^6$ possibilities.

For the second one there are as many equivalence classes as unique sums of two elements. You can make any number from $2$ to $500.$

Comment: Thanks! for 2, How can I count the unique sums? I still don't get it.

Comment: @Justagirl it's just every number  you can write as the sum of two elements of the set {1,2,3, ... 250}. So 1+ 1 =2, 1+2 =3, 1+3 =4 .... 2+2=4, 2+3  = 5... etc. There will be a lot of repeats if you count this way but it's pretty easy to figure out what set of numbers come out. Each of these will represent an equivalence class, so for instance (1,3) and (2,2) are both in the equivalence class of pairs that sum to 4. (250,250) is the only element of the equivalence class of pairs that sum to 500, etc. Are there pairs that sum to 501? 499? What are the possibilities?

Comment: Oh ok, I get the question now but I still don't know how to count them :(

Comment: @Justagirl You can make any number from 2 to 500 as the sum of two elements of {1,2,3,..250}. You can count the numbers between 2 and 500.

Comment: Alright. Thank you! I understand